# What is the maximum size of document I can save in firebase collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, payload, image-size

I'm trying to save a user profile, which contains 7-8 text fields with up to 500 words each, and three pictures. I'm converting images to Base64 URL and storing the URL in respective fields When the user tries to save the profile, it shows an error that the payload size exceeds the allowed limit. [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) says that the maximum size for a document can be 1MB, which is too low in my case. Is there any way to increase the size? or any other way around?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to increase the size?

AFAIK there is no way to increase the limit of 1MiB for the size of a document.

> Any other way around?

In your case you could save the images in Cloud Storage and only save their URL in the Firestore document. You'll find the doc for Cloud Storage [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).

If this is not sufficient you will need to distribute the data for one use profile among different Firestore Documents. To identify them, you could either group them in a subcollection or save in a dedicated field a common unique ID (e.g. the document ID of the first one).

Comment: I'll mention I do exactly this - URLs in Firestore, images in Storage - you may need to setup/build/design a folder structure that parallels your firestore schema for convenience, which is what I did.  You could also just let Storage maintain document ID's for you, but that makes it harder to maintain.

Comment: @LeadDreamer Sounds interesting, I have created a folder in storage against each user, but I'm not sure how I can maintain document ID through Storage. For now, I'm storing image URL in respective fields of user document.

Comment: Qurat I do both.  If user wants to give a URL for an image, I just use that in the document.  If they want to upload, I load it over into Storage (the refpath structure is almost identical to Firestore, so you can use the documentid for the storage file id), then store the URL to *that* in the document.